# jQuery record/play mouse moves

Tags: jquery, timer, resize, mouse, record

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dEXpY/)

How it works:

> Press the "record" button and start clicking in the red div, the black box will start to follow your clicks, use the mouse wheel inside the black box only to resize it. 
>   When you are done, press the play button.
>   The reset button resets the coordinates and the counter.

It is not perfect, I'm a beginner in jQuery, but at least it works...

I'm writing this question because I want to implement some kind of a timer, that counts in milliseconds and every millisecond is stored in an array.
And in that array, for every millisecond, the current coordinates and size of the box are stored, so when you run it, it will move and resize the box after the exact time interval in which you "recorded it".

Ex:

```
00:00 - top:0px, left:0px, width:50px, height:50px
00:10 - top:0px, left:0px, width:50px, height:50px
00:20 - top:0px, left:0px, width:50px, height:50px
00:30 - top:0px, left:0px, width:50px, height:50px
00:40 - top:110px, left:20px, width:50px, height:50px
...
01:40 - top:110px, left:20px, width:70px, height:70px
01:50 - top:310px, left:250px, width:70px, height:70px
...
04:20 - top:17px, left:231px, width:10px, height:10px
...
10:50 - top:502px, left:354px, width:100px, height:100px
```

I hope I explained it well..

Comment: That's pretty damn clever for a 'beginner' ;)

Comment: Thanks @Rob  :) It was given to me as a task from my employer, to understand and learn jQuery faster by myself, but the timer thing is my idea to make it "smoother" and it bugs me now..

Comment: Just so you know, the resizer is VERY glitchy, if i click somewhere, resize it, and then click somewhere else, when I replay it it: moves the square, moves it again, and then resizes it at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/dEXpY/26/
Sorry, no comments in the code, so you'll have to figure it out yourself. I also fixed the resizing bug that I said in the comment on your question, and I also made it so that when you click start the text in the record button changes back to record.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you, I played with my version a little, but I left it aside because no one replied :D I did change some things but I didn't implement timed animations. I'll look into this when I have some free time again. I'll post my version now if you are interested :)

Comment: I see. Apparently my version does not have the trace thing and the movement speed setter (and I don't have the time to implement those), but in case you are interested the actionsArr is an array of objects representing each action. Each object has the time (in milliseconds since the user clicked record) that the action occured, the left and top values, and the height and width values. If you are wondering how I made the play button works, I'll explain in the next comment because this one is running out of characters

Comment: The play button works by the iterate function. This is instead of a loop. The j variable is the counter. For every action that is in the actionsArr array, iterate is called. Here is what iterate does: It makes sure that the current action exists, and if so creates a function onTimer, which is to be called when the time specified by the time of the current action has passed. This means that for every action there is, a function that resizes and moves the square appropriately is set to run after the correct amount of time. Iterate then increments the counter, before calling itself again.

Comment: If you are wondering about the onTimer.j part, I can explain. j, the counter variable for iterate, is incremented each time that iterate is called. iterate is called all of the times necessary virtually instantly. This means that by the time the onTimers start executing, j will already be set to actionsArr's length, therefore meaning that the onTimers will all be acting on a nonexistent index of actionsArr (because at this point actionsArr[j] is undefined because j is set to the arrays length of actionsArr because iterate incremented it for every element of actionsArr). A little known fact is

Comment: that that you can add properties to a function as if it were an object, and you can also read those. And the function will still work. So, when iterate is called, j is the current index. onTimer is a local variable, so this effectively means that when onTimer is executed it can refer to the correct value of j by this.j. I know that is really confusing but hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to use

```
new Date().getTime(); //  gets the time value in milliseconds from a current date.
```

New variables:

```
clickTime = [];
timeDiffs = [];
start = 0;
```

Firstly record start time when the **record** button is pressed.
Then, every time the click event happens update **clickTime** with current time in milliseconds.

Then, in click event do the following:

```
if(i == 0){
  timeDiffs[i] = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
}else{
  timeDiffs[i] = new Date().getTime() - clickTime[i-1];
}
```

For the first time calculate the time difference between current time and **start**. For next clicks subtract last **clickTime** from current time so we will get a difference between consequent clicks in milliseconds.

That's all, now just

```
$(".inner").animate( { left: arrX[i], top: arrY[i]}, timeDiffs[i]);
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vARwz/

I see that you want do the things 'after the exact time interval' so maybe you can use jQuery **.delay()** method.

I hope, I gave you a clue, how to do what you want.